# Access to Ubuntu Server 12.04 offline

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, offline

How to login in Ubuntu Server when server is offline? After start booting ubuntu screen show nothing (refresh rate is out of range). I try Ctrl + Alt + F1 and other and I still have not access to my server. I can't login by ssh, because I broken /etc/network/interface and server is completely offline.
Any suggestion?
Sorry for my english, it isn't my native language.

Comment: Try with `ctrl+alt+f1` to reach console

Comment: I tried from ctrl+alt+F1 to ctrl+alt+F12 and nothing was changed

Comment: Try recovery mode from boot meni, if see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot the machine with a ubuntu installation cd. Then select "try ubuntu" and mount the server disk. From there you can try to troubleshoot any issues. Or alternatively you can make a backup of the machine and do a reinstallation (the system /home /etc and /var are most likely sufficient for a backup).

If there's something wrong with the network configuration have a look at `/etc/network/interfaces`.

If you do a reinstallation beware of any databases stored on the computer: Databases cannot be recovered by just copying the configuration folders (in most cases).